# flowbite + Carousel doesn't worked when i navigate to a different page and then come back

Tags: flowbite

I made infinity Carousel using flowbite library.
my project based on React, TypeScript, Vite ,TailwindCSS.

My Question is My Carousel doesn't work when i navigate to a different page and then come back.

Carousel is on the main Home page ('/').
first page showed the Carousel very well. but as i mentioned, when come back from the other page Carousel doesn't work!

**only i refresh the page , then the Carousel re-Show up **

Below is my current code.
[img - first showd up on ('/)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gqoy.png)

```
import "flowbite";

import slider1 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider1.png";
import slider2 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider2.png";
import slider3 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider3.png";
import slider4 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider4.png";
import slider5 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider5.png";
import slider6 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider6.png";
import slider7 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider7.png";
import slider8 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider8.png";
import slider9 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider9.png";
import slider10 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider10.png";
import slider11 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider11.png";
import slider12 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider12.png";
import slider13 from "@/assets/img/slider/slider13.png";

"flowbite";

const Slider = () => {
    const imgArr = [
        slider1,
        slider2,
        slider3,
        slider4,
        slider5,
        slider6,
        slider7,
        slider8,
        slider9,
        slider10,
        slider11,
        slider12,
        slider13,
    ];


    return (
        <div
            // ref={carouselRef}
            id="default-carousel"
            className="relative w-full"
            data-carousel="slide"
        >
            <div className="relative h-80 overflow-hidden rounded-lg md:h-[420px]">
                {imgArr.map((img, idx) => (
                    <div

                        className="hidden duration-700 ease-in-out"
                        data-carousel-item
                        key={idx}
                    >
                        
                        <img
                            src={img}
                            alt={`Image ${idx}`}
                            className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full opacity-70"
                        />
                        
                        <img
                            src={img}
                            alt={`Image ${idx}`}
                            className="absolute w-4/5 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 h-3/4 top-1/2 left-1/2"
                        />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>


        </div>
    );
};

export default Slider;
```

below pic is status of after come back.

[img - not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcyWp.png)

I checked the network, but no problem to download the img. d

I refereed this link => [flowbite(carousel)](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/carousel/)

please give me advice.

I tried custom Carousel .. and also tried to use [Flowbite for React.](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/carousel)

but using Flowbite React was not pretty that i expected and also have some error.